# neo4j number accuracy

Tags: neo4j

i am currently using neo4j-community(2.2.2) and found that this cypher query does not work as one expect:

```
    CREATE (n:Node {some_attribute:602867661010247681}) RETURN n
```

and at the end you found that on the node that was just created, that property has the value *'602867661010247700'*. I dig about this issue, but did not found any documentation or feasible solution to this, anyone knows if is something that has not been properly configured on my neo4j default installation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Neo4j Browser messing up the value when displaying it.

If you check the node created via the Neo4j shell, you'll find that it has been saved with the correct value.

Comment: Thank you Luanne, i tested this with python and is totally related with the neo4j web browser.